# Could someone help me understand the order of operations in the following line of MATLAB code?

Tags: python, matlab

I have a MATLAB program which I am trying to convert to Python. The following line of code is from the MATLAB program. I am unable to understand its order of operations. Could someone help me breakdown the following line into its simplest components?

```
first_diameter = 5e-9
last_diameter = 15e-6
lkdiam = 73     

logdp = 10.^(log10(first_diameter):(log10(last_diameter)-log10(first_diameter))/lkmdiam:log10(last_diameter))';
```

The output is as follows:

```
logdp =

5.00000000000000e-09
5.57958377035184e-09
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
1.34418628856379e-05
1.50000000000000e-05
```

`logdp` contains 74 rows and 1 column.

Comment: Split it up according to parentheses. The colon operator has lowest precedence, its `start:step:stop`, and generates an array of values, `stop` included if it is hit exactly by the steps.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Thank you very much, Cris. This is the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np

lkmdiam = 73
log_10_first_diameter = 5e-09
log_10_last_diameter = 1.5e-05
log_dp = np.transpose(pow(10, np.arange(log_10_first_diameter, log_10_last_diameter, ((log_10_last_diameter - log_10_first_diameter)/lkmdiam))))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.